# magento add suggested url in custom search Extension same as catalog search

Tags: catalogsearch

How to  add suggested url in custom search Extension same as catalog search like the below screen shot

http://screencast.com/t/3mipRH9p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replicate the suggestion box of the catalog.
In the frontend you need to have something like this below the search box

```
<div id="custom_search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var customSearchForm = new Varien.searchForm('id_of_the_form', 'id_of_the_search_input', '<?php echo $this->__('Some placeholder here') ?>');
        customSearchForm .initAutocomplete('<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/controller/search') ?>', 'custom_search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

then you need to create a method `searchAction` in one of the contrllers from your custom module that must return an `<ul>`element with `<li>` elements like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I am trying to call top menu catalog search in footer . I used this code in my static Block {{block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}} .Its showing search input Field without suggession Can i know why this .its showing suggessions in topSearch But not in footer . Looking for your reply

Comment: You see the suggestion at the top because you have 2 elements with the same id in your page. clone the form.mini template and use that one in the footer. Just change the ids of the html elements.

Comment: I cloned with name {{block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/formpart.mini.phtml"}} also change the id <form id="search_mini_formpart" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">         <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_formpart', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('') ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>  </script>  But still not working

Comment: Looking for your reply Please

Comment: Change the var name `searchForm` to something else. Change the `search_autocomplete` id to something else

Comment: <form id="search_mini_form_part" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">  <div id="search_autocomplete_part" class="search-autocomplete"></div>  <script type="text/javascript">
var searchFormPart = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form_part', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('') ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete_part');
       </script> i did that also but no luck  {{block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/formpart.mini.phtml"}}

Comment: Some thing is working please check the below screen its coming while i inspect but its display none always how to manage this i was thinking if its working then everything is fine

Comment: Yes i did it Thanks for your Help You are Great